# Counting using modulo (discrete problem)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am having trouble with my discrete h/w. I (kinda) understand the problem but I am stuck on how to write/format the solution. Please help!

16.

a) To each integer $n$ we assign an ordered pair $p(n)$ whose members are the remainders when $n$ is divided by $3$ and $4$ respectively. For example, $p(5)$ and $p(17)$ are both equal to $(2, 1)$. If ten thousand integers are chosen at random, how many can you say for certain must have the same value for $p$?

b) Repeat part (a) with the divisors $3$ and $4$ replaced by $4$ and $6$.

Answer (score 0):

I'll do part a) to give you the idea, you can do part b) yourself.

By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, the solution $n \mod 3 = a, n \mod 4 = b$ is unique for $0 \le n \le 11$, so all 12 values of $p$ are possible. Now apply the pigeonhole principle to see that at least $\lfloor (10000 - 1)/12\rfloor + 1= 834$ have the same value for $p$.

Comment: would it be wrong to just take the ceiling of 10000/12?

Comment: @user18018 No it wouldn't, it's the same thing.